# Include OS info in log

Tags: python, pandas, python-logging

I'm trying to include the user and computer name running the Python script in the log. This is what I've done so far:

```
import logging
import os
import pandas as pd

user = os.getlogin()
computer = os.environ['COMPUTERNAME']

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='log.txt', filemode='w', format='%(filename)s|Line - %(lineno)s|%(asctime)s|%(levelname)s|%(message)s',datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

log = pd.read_csv('log.txt', sep='|', header=None)
log.columns = ['Job_Name', 'Line', 'Date_Time', 'Level', 'Message']

for i, row in log.iterrows():
    log.at[i,'Computer'] = computer
    log.at[i,'User'] = user
```

I'm creating 2 variables for the user and computer. Then grab the log, put it in a df, and append the variables. The df then gets imported into a SQL Server DB.

Is there a better way?

I'm using Python 3.10.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set an entire column to one value, Pandas has a shortcut for that:

```py
log['Computer'] = computer
```

This also creates the column if it doesn't exist.